multiple same name buttons in playwright are not being clicked
We have a page where-in there is a button named "Purchase" and when it is clicked it will open a modal with another button named "Purchase" so there will be 2 buttons with name "Purchase" in the DOM.
I tried the code below but it is not working. By the way, the page is built in react. Does anyone has idea on this?
    const buttons = await page.$$('button'); // Get all buttons on the page
    const purchaseButtons = buttons.filter(async button => {
        const buttonText = await button.innerText(); // Get the text of the button
        return buttonText === 'Purchase'; // Check if the button text matches
    });

    // Assuming there are at least two buttons with the name 'Purchase'
    if (purchaseButtons.length >= 2) {
        await purchaseButtons[1].click(); // Click the second button with the name 'Purchase'
    } else {
        console.error('There are not enough buttons with the name "Purchase"');
    }


Please share your page so the example is complete and runnable. What does "not working" mean? .filter() doesn't work with async. Use a for..of loop.

Use native Playwright syntax for Locator istead of $$.
  const buttons = page.locator("button", { hasText: "Purchase" });
  
  // since toHaveCount() can't be used as toBeGreaterThan() - this will assure that you have minimum 2 buttons
  await expect(buttons.nth(1), "2nd button should be visible").toBeVisible(); 
  
  // instead of this
  // await expect(buttons.first()).toBeVisible();
  // const count = await buttons.count();
  // expect(count).toBeGreaterThan(2);

  // or this
  // await expect(buttons).not.toHaveCount(0);
  // await expect(buttons).not.toHaveCount(1);


  await buttons.nth(1).click();

